# PHP - trying to get an array item reduced by one $array[$var - 1]

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get an array item with a `$variable - 1`.

What I am trying to do:

I have an array of days in a month

```
$monthsArray = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
```

I have a variable which is the month

```
$monthOfDeparture = mb_substr($departureDate, 3, 4);
```

which has the value of 01 for January etc.

I am trying to get the correct month by

```
$theMonth = $monthsArray[$monthOfDeparture - 1]
```

What I actually get is the month of departure ie: March (31) instead of February (28) if `$monthOfDeparture = 03`.

Any help would be welcome.

Providing code: note the `$arrivalDate` and `$departureDate` look like this `23-02-21` (dd-mm-yy)

```
$arrivalDateNumber = mb_substr($arrivalDate, 0, 1);
$departureDateNumber = mb_substr($departureDate, 0, 1);
                    
$monthOfArrival = mb_substr($arrivalDate, 3, 4);
$monthOfDeparture = mb_substr($departureDate, 3, 4);
                    
$monthsArray = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
                    
if( $departureDateNumber < $arrivalDateNumber) {
    $depNumTwo = $monthsArray[$monthOfDeparture - 1];
    $lodgingNights = $depNumTwo - $arrivalDateNumber + $departureDateNumber; 
    $pay = $lodgingNights * $price_per_night;
}else{
    $lodgingNights = $departureDateNumber - $arrivalDateNumber;
    $pay = $lodgingNights * $price_per_night;
}
```

**Edit**

There was an error my logic. What I wanted to do was:

```
// if the number of days in departure is greater then the number of days in arrival 
if( $departureDateNumber < $arrivalDateNumber) {
    //get the number of days in the month of arrival
    $arrNumTwo = $monthsArray[$monthOfArrival];
    //the user will stay: total number of days in arrival month - starting date of arrival + days in the next month
    $lodgingNights = $arrNumTwo - $arrivalDateNumber + $departureDateNumber; 
    $pay = $lodgingNights * $price_per_night;
}else{
    $lodgingNights = $departureDateNumber - $arrivalDateNumber;
    $pay = $lodgingNights * $price_per_night;
}
```

The problem I am having now is that I get *Notice: Undefined index: 02-2 in* my path on line `$arrNumTwo = $monthsArray[$monthOfArrival];` I guess that is becouse of this code segment `$monthOfArrival = mb_substr($arrivalDate, 3, 4);` although I don't know why it dosesn't just take the 3rd and 4th character.

Edit nmb xy.
Figured out I misnderstood how substr works. Needed to use `$monthOfArrival = mb_substr($arrivalDate, 3, 2);`

Comment: Please share more details, like sample code that helps to reproduce your problem

Comment: `'03' - 1` is `2`, and the value at index `2` in your array _is_ `31`. You simply want minus two, not minus one.

Comment: So "correct month" would be "previous month"?

Comment: yes, the correct month would be previous month (becouse the array starts wtih 0 instead of 1)

Comment: _“becouse the array starts wtih 0 instead of 1”_ - only if you want it to, it is easy to make it start from a different index, by explicitly specifying which one to use for the first item. `$monthsArray = [1 => 31, 28, 31, …]` would get you the whole thing indexed starting with 1.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you. I did try it out, changed `$monthsArray = [ 1 => 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];` and `$depNumTwo = $monthsArray[$monthOfDeparture];` but now I get *Notice: Undefined index: 03-2 in* mypath

Comment: @CBroe that should be an answer not just comment. - index is a clue in this case and `1=>31` solves it easy.

Comment: Cast your month value to an integer. Though, I still don't understand how reindexing would fix this. The `-1` solution with the array starting at 0 would be the same as not modifying the value with the array starting at 1. The logic you have stated in your question seems to indicate you're not looking for the month of departure, but rather the month before. Can you clarify what your expected value would be for `03`?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. why do I get 03-1. Now that I am looking up the number in the index I get 03-1. Why is that?

Comment: Though, observing the purpose of your code after the update, you would benefit by dropping this whole code block and rewriting everything using `DateTime`.

Comment: btw you're not accounting for leap years, 29 days in feb

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I know. I'll get to it later =)

Comment: Avoid all of these problems by applying the `DateTime` logic @Martijn suggested in his answer. Arrays, undefined index notices, leap days... all gone if you switch to that.

Comment: What is `$arrivalDate`? is it `YYYY-MM-DD`?  Why do you need multibyte substr() support?  I think don't cut your input date at all, feed it to a date function or class and then get the `t` value.

Comment: it's `dd-mm-yy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not an answer to your placed question, this might be an answer worth your while:

```
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $theMonth, $year);
```

<sup>*You might need to do a `+2000` for the $year</sup>

[Docs for cal_days_in_month](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php). This has the added bonus of working in leap years.

---

Alternatively you can use DateTime (which I recommend). Datetime seems a bit intimidating in the beginning, but has a lot of features which make your life a lot easier. Example:

```
$arrival = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-y", $arrivalDate);
$departure = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-y", $departureDate);
```

You can compare those with eachother (eg `if( $departure < $arrival) {}`) and you can get the diff a lot easier:

```
$diff = $arrival->diff($departure)->days;
```

Comment: Side note: one could use `->days` in place of `->format('%a')`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll give it a try if I don't solve this

Comment: Accepting this anwser as there is a consensus this is the best way. The problem was actually with my logic and missunderstanding of `substr`.

Comment: Likely to be duplicate advice on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WeAreDoomed I still recommend you check out my datetime part of the answer. I can promise you that that'll be worth the hassle. If not now, than the next time you need it :)

Comment: I belive you. =) I will get to it, but right now I still have way to many things to do. Thank you for the pointers.